# How to insert date

Tags: java, date, jdbc

I wrote a java code for inserting the current date but when I try to run it exception occurs:

```
public void Session_Table_Update (String Update_User) throws SQLException{
           String  SQL_Statement = null;
           error_Message = null;
            if (ds == null) throw new SQLException( error_Database = "No data source");      
       Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            if (conn == null) throw new SQLException( error_Database = "No connection");      

       try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            boolean committed = false;
                try {
                    SQL_Statement = "INSERT INTO USERS (LAST_LOGIN) VALUES (?,?,?) WHERE USERZ ="+ Update_User;

                       PreparedStatement insertQuery = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_Statement);
                       insertQuery.setString(3, "2.2.2011");

                       insertQuery.executeUpdate();                  


                       conn.commit();
                       committed = true;
                 } finally {
                       if (!committed) conn.rollback();
                       }
            }
                finally {               
                conn.close();

                }  

           return;
       }
```

Can you help me to fix the problem?

Comment: More importantingly, what exception do you get? They usually contain the whole answer at its own.

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three parameters (`?` characters) in your query, so you need to set that many parameters. You're only setting one of these (the third one), so you need to have

```
insertQuery.setString(1, "something");
insertQuery.setString(2, "something else");
insertQuery.setString(3, "2.2.2011");
```

Or another `set*` method depending on your data type. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

As BalusC says, to set a date it would be better to use the `setDate()` method on your `PreparedStatement`. However, as you're using Oracle, you may also consider using the `TO_DATE` Oracle function (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm), which converts a string to an Oracle date. e.g.

```
"INSERT INTO USERS (LAST_LOGIN) VALUES (?,?,TO_DATE(?, 'D.M.YYYY')) WHERE USERZ ="+ Update_User;
```

The format string can be changed to suit your needs

Answer (score 5):

> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

You have definied 3 value placeholders `(?,?,?)`:

```
SQL_Statement = "INSERT INTO USERS (LAST_LOGIN) VALUES (?,?,?) WHERE USERZ ="+ Update_User;
```

However, you're setting only 1 value instead of 3.

```
insertQuery.setString(3, "2.2.2011");
```

You need to replace `(?,?,?)` by `(?)`.

```
SQL_Statement = "INSERT INTO USERS (LAST_LOGIN) VALUES (?) WHERE USERZ ="+ Update_User;
// ...
insertQuery.setString(1, "2.2.2011");
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I also recommend to replace `Update_User` by another placeholder to avoid a SQL injection hole.

```
SQL_Statement = "INSERT INTO USERS (LAST_LOGIN) VALUES (?) WHERE USERZ = ?";
// ...
insertQuery.setString(1, "2.2.2011");
insertQuery.setString(2, Update_User); // Or should it be `setLong()`?
```

I also recommend to make the `LAST_LOGIN` a `DATE` type instead of apparently a `VARCHAR` and then set it by `setDate()`. This way you will more easily be able to let the DB select/sort the results based on date at a later point.

Last but not least, please read on the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). PHP-style method and variable names makes your Java code harder to read to normal Java developers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a `WHERE` clause on an `INSERT` statement in SQL.  It looks to me like you want to set the last login time for a user that is already in the table, instead of adding a row to the table.  In that case, you need to use an `UPDATE` statement instead, something like

```
SQL_Statement = "UPDATE USERS SET LAST_LOGIN = ? WHERE USERZ = ?";
PreparedStatement insertQuery = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_Statement);
insertQuery.setString(1, "2.2.2011");
insertQuery.setString(2, Update_User);
```

I agree with BalusC in that you should also pass the username in using a placeholder rather than concatenating it to the SQL string.

However, I can't be sure that setting the date as a string (`2.2.2011`) as you are doing will work.  That very much depends on which database you are using.